# getter not working after constructor shows correct value

Tags: php, oop, constructor

This seems pretty simple. I'm basically manipulating an input text file and trying to output the file in a specific format. Before I can do that, I need the `$team->getWins` getter to return the correct value. The format of the input file is team name, wins, losses. Here is the input text file `mlb_nl_2011.txt`:

```
Phillies 102 60
Braves 89 73
Nationals 80 81
Mets 77 85
Marlins 72 90
Brewers 96 66
Cardinals 90 72
Reds 79 83
Pirates 72 90
Cubs 71 91
Astros 56 106
DBacks 94 68
Giants 86 76
Dodgers 82 79
Rockies 73 89
Padres 71 91
```

Here is the `Team.php` file:

```
<?php

class Team {

  private $name;
  private $wins;
  private $loss;

  public function __construct($name, $wins, $loss) {
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->wins = $wins;
    $this->loss = $loss;

    echo $this->name ." ";
    echo $this->wins ." ";
    echo $this->loss ."\n";
  }

  public function getName() {
    return $this->name;
  }

  public function getWins() {
    return $this->wins;
  }

  public function getLosses() {
    return $this->loss;
  }

  public function getWinPercentage() {
    return $this->wins / ($this->wins + $this->loss);
  }

  public function __toString() {
    return $this->name . " (" . $this->wins . ", " . $this->loss . ")";
  }

}

?>
```

Here is my main **PHP** file.

```
<?php

include_once("Team.php");

  $file_handle = fopen("mlb_nl_2011.txt", "r");

  $teams = array();
  $counter = 0;

  while(!feof($file_handle)) { 
            $line_data = fgets($file_handle);
            $line_data_array = explode(' ',trim($line_data));
            $team = new Team($line_data_array[0],$line_data_array[1],$line_data_array[2]);
            $teams[$counter] = $team;
            $counter++;
  }

  print_r($teams);
  //looks good through this point

  $output_file = "mlb_nl_2011_results.txt";
  $opened_file = fopen($output_file, 'a');

  foreach($teams as $team) {
    $win = $team->getWins();
    $los = $team->getLosses();
    echo $win ." ". $los."\n";
    $name = $team->getName();
    echo fprintf($opened_file, "%s  %d\n", $name, $win_per);
  }
  fclose($opened_file);

?>
```

At the point when I do the `print_r($teams)`, all the values are correct. I get a print similar to this for each team:

```
[15] => Team Object
        (
            [name:Team:private] => Padres
            [wins:Team:private] => 71
            [loss:Team:private] => 91
        )
```

But when I do the print at `echo $win ." ". $los."\n";` I get this:

```
102 60
1289 73
1080 81
1377 85
872 90
1196 66
1190 72
1379 83
872 90
1171 91
856 106
1094 68
1086 76
1082 79
1173 89
1171 91
```

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unexpected digits at the beginning of each row (except the first one) are results of this statement...

```
echo fprintf($opened_file, "%s  %d\n", $name, $win_per);
```

... as [**fprintf**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fprintf.php) returns the length of the string written to a stream, and `echo` sends this result to standard output (screen in this case, obviously). Hence, for example, you got `'12'` printed for the second row, immediately followed by `'89 73\n'` part.

The solution is obvious too: just get rid of `echo` here. Actually, using `echo print ... ;` constructs in the real code is rarely a good idea. )